# Getting syntax error on compiling with sass- First attempt using it

Tags: sass

SCSS

```
.footer-color{
    @include linear-gradient(lighten(black, 20%), black);
    }


    @mixin linear-gradient($fromColor, $toColor) {
      background-color: $toColor;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from($fromColor), to($toColor));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
      background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
      background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor); 
      background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor); 
      background-image:         linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
    }
```

its not specifying where it is coming from but i believe it has something to do with the .footer-color. Not 100% sure how to fix as i said this is my first attempt at anything using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your mixin before your `.footer-color` class and it should work fine

Comment: thanks always something stupid when you're starting off